How to open a movie on netflix tv app from another android app
I am developing a react native app where  I need to open a netflix movie direct withpout landing on home page.
It is my code
const netflixLink = 'https://www.netflix.com/watch/81637260';

    const openNetflix = async () => {
        try {
            await Linking.openURL(netflixLink);
            const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(netflixLink);
            if (supported) {
                await Linking.openURL(netflixLink);
            } else {
                showAlert(`Don't know how to open this URL: ${netflixLink}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            showAlert('An error occurred: ' + error.message);
        }
    };

But it is always landing on netflix home page instead of movie page
Solution of this url binding

Might be because Netflix does not know the profile to use (as "who" it needs to open the movie, and whose suggestions the movie will influence later), and/or there are also redirects based on location (some movies are unavailable in some countries), being logged in/out, "kids" setting being turned on...
